# Stuck increasing VSA storage cluster size

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I am trying to increase the size of a VSA cluster in vCenter 5.5.0.

I stopped all the VMs running on the VSADs-n datastores, put the VSA cluster in Maintenance Mode and started the Increase wizard in the VSA Manager.

Unfortunately it seems to be stuck on "Increasing VSA Storage Capacity".
The progress bar hasn't moved from the start[image], and I've got a message underneath saying:

> Increase Storage Warning: Extending VMDK on VSA-1 and waited 300 seconds for storage entities to come online. Please stop I/Os on the VSA datastores for increase storage to continue

This updates every 5 minutes, and it's on 1200 seconds now.

I can't stop the process now, having started it:

> Increase storage operation in progress. Cannot be interrupted.

I am starting to get a little worried now!  How can I fix this?  How can I gracefully abort the resize?

Comment: Is that product supported anymore?

Answer (score 2):

After a slightly harrowing half hour, it timed out and aborted gracefully, saying:

> Increase Storage Warning: Extending VMDK on VSA-1 and waited 1800 seconds for storage entities to come online. Please stop I/Os on the VSA datastores for increase storage to continue
>
> Increase Storage Failed: Failed to grow storage: Timed out waiting for storage entities to come online

Based on the above error, I decided to try *not* putting the cluster in maintenance mode, and this worked.

It took around half an hour to complete.  It restarted each VSA VM and performed a quick resync operation each time.  The last half of the process didn't trigger any further Tasks in the bottom pane, but it eventually completed successfully.